# XML to String Builder

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, xsd

I have an XML document which contains multiple `DETAIL` elements.  Each `DETAIL` element can contain `UpdateDate` and `Description` attributes.  For instance, here is a short example:

```
<MyDocument>
    <DETAIL UpdateDate='18-Sept-2012' />
    <DETAIL UpdateDate='18-Sept-2012' Description='A description goes here' />
</MyDocument>
```

I need to transform the XML so that all the attributes become child elements, for instance:

```
<MyDocument>
    <DETAIL>
        <UpdateDate>18-Sept-2012</UpdateDate>
    </DETAIL>
    <DETAIL>
        <UpdateDate>18-Sept-2012</UpdateDate>
        <Description>A description goes here</Description>
    </DETAIL>
</MyDocument>
```

The method I am using to transform the XML looks like this:

```
Function ProcessDetail(ByVal xmlText As String) As String
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlText)
    Dim sDetail As New StringBuilder()
    sDetail.Append("<DETAIL>")
    For Each detailNode As XmlNode In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DETAIL")
        If Not detailNode.Attributes Is Nothing Then
            For Each attribute As XmlAttribute In detailNode.Attributes
                sDetail.Append("<" & attribute.Name.ToUpper & ">" & attribute.Value & "</" & attribute.Name.ToUpper & ">")
            Next
        End If
    Next
    sDetail.Append("</DETAIL>")
    Return sDetail.ToString()
End Function
```

This method works fine for most `DETAIL` elements, but it fails when it tries to transform an element that looks like this:

```
<DETAIL Description='Problem:<br><br>CRS750 dumps when panel F is opened' />
```

Since it has reserved charaters, such as `<` and `>` in the attribute value, it throws an exception that says:

```
error message - `'<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 1, position 1326.`
```

How can I fix my method so that it can transform these types of `DETAIL` elements without throwing an exception?

Comment: I modified your question significantly to more clearly state what I think your problem is.  Please review it and let me know whether or not you think I am understanding your problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid XML and therefore is practically impossible to parse, certainly not with any standard XML parser library.  If possible, fix the code that generates the XML so that the reserved characters are properly escaped (e.g. `>` should be changed to `&gt;`).  To fix it, an XML parser object such as `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` should be used to generate the XML rather than building it directly through string concatenation.  However, if it is too difficult to change that, at the very least, you should call `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode` on each node value before concatenating it to the XML document string.

If the code that generates the XML cannot be fixed, you will have to manually parse the invalid XML, yourself, by removing the `"<DETAIL Description='"` from the beginning of the string, and the `"' />"` from the end of the string.  But that only works if that is the complete string and it always has that same exact starting and ending format.

Comment: Am inserting a DETAIL TAG in the beginning and end to make it valid.So my strung builder will look like <DETAIL><UPDATEDATE>18th Sept<UPDATEDATE><DETAIL> . I'm manually adding the DETAIL & UPDATE elements .

Comment: Please show a simple example of code that duplicates the problem and I will show you how to fix it.  Please add the example to your original question rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: The simple answer is that you should be using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` to insert the `DETAIL` element rather than simply concatenating strings using the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Can I please message you the code I have . Unable to paste it here due to limit of characters . Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is to not only answer your individual question, but to do so in a way that benefits others with similar questions in the future.  It wouldn't benefit anyone for this question to remain half asked and half answered.  I'm not asking you to copy your entire code into your question.  I was just suggesting that you create a simplistic example of code that has the same problem.  I will update my answer to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Function ProcessDetail() As String
        Dim detailNode As XmlNode
        sDetail.Append("<DETAIL>")
        detailNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DETAIL")
        For Each detailNode In detailNodeList
            xmlAttributes = detailNode.Attributes
            If Not xmlAttributes Is Nothing Then
                For Each xmlAttribute In detailNode.Attributes
                    sDetail.Append("<" & xmlAttribute.Name.ToUpper & ">" & xmlAttribute.Value & "</" & xmlAttribute.Name.ToUpper & ">")
                Next
            End If
        Next
        sDetail.Append("</DETAIL>")

Comment: The above is the function am using to generate the string for the Detail Element Tag in my XML . The output comes out to be something like this.

Comment: <DETAIL>
  <UPDATEDATE>18-Sept-2012</UPDATEDATE> 
  <AUDIENCE>External</AUDIENCE> 
  <TYPE>Cumulative/Service Pack/Patch Release DUCT</TYPE> 
  <LANGUAGE>English</LANGUAGE> 
  </DETAIL>

Comment: Ok, got it.  I updated your question to include that example.  I will work on a fix and post it in my answer soon.